# Send tweets from Mac OSX without using tweet sheet

Tags: macos, twitter

So I'd like to send tweets from a mac osx app, but I'm just looking for some advice before I start.

Should I use the Social/Accounts frame work and tweet out that way or should I use some sort of library and the twitter API, if so, which one?

I would really like not to use the tweet sheet interface apple provides as I'd like to tweet on behalf of the user (with their permission, of course!). Pretty much want to use a UI that I designed rather than the tweet sheet. I *only* want to tweet from the user, I have no interest in reading their feed etc.

I've done a few iOS apps but this would be my first Mac OS X app so I'm just not too sure on whats out there and what's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this pod: https://github.com/nst/STTwitter

Does what it says on the tin. Perfect.